# Why istream object can be used as a bool expression?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, istream

Does anyone know why istream object can be used as bool expression? For example:

```
ifstream input("tmp");
int iValue;
while (input >> iValue)
    //do something;
```

Here `input >> iValue` returns a reference to the ifstream object. I want to know why this object can be used as a bool expression.
I look into the ifstream class and find that this may be due to the following member function:

```
operator void * ( ) const;
```

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) for detail about this function.
If it is, can anyone explain this function to me? The prototype of this function is different from usual operator overload declaration. What is the return type of this function? 
If it is not, then what is the reason that ifstream object can be used as bool expression?
Looking forward to your help!

cheng

Comment: Well asked question despite having a straight forward answer.

Comment: Since C++11 there is actually `explicit operator bool()`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The exact mechanism that enables use of an istream as a boolean expression, was changed in C++11. Previously is was an implicit conversion to `void*`, as you've found. In C++11 it is instead an `explicit` conversion to `bool`.

Use of an istream or ostream in a boolean expression was enabled so that C++ programmers could continue to use *an expression with side-effects* as the condition of a `while` or `for` loop:

```
SomeType v;

while( stream >> v )
{
    // ...
}
```

And the reason that programmers do that and want that, is that it gives more concise code, code that is easier to take in at a glance, than e.g. …

```
for( ;; )
{
    SomeType v;
    
    stream >> v;
    if( stream.fail() )
    {
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

However, in some cases even such a verbose structure can be preferable. It depends.

Answer (score 7):

It's a cast operator to the given type. `operator T ()` is a cast operator to the type T. In the `if` statement, the `ifstream` is converted to `void*`, and then the `void*` converted to `bool`.

Comment: `void* converted to bool` .. that's not correct. Rather I would say, `void* is compared to 0`.

Comment: Thanks for replying so soon, I got it. I have one more question: if there are two cast operator functions in a class, one to int and the other to int*. For the call if (obj), which case operation function will be called? Why?  Thanks.

Comment: @iammilind: It is correct. The pointer is converted to `bool`. Check §4.12 and §6.4.1.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, Are you referring to C++11. AFAIK, in C++03, it's just plain `void*` which is compared with `0`. [P.S.: I haven't downvoted this answer.]

Comment: @iammilind: The reference numbers I gave are from the C++11 standard. The numbering in C++03 could be different. *But the behaviour is the same*. `void*` is convertible to `bool` and everything is converted to `bool` in `if`s.

Comment: Comparison to 0 is how the conversion is implemented, but it is entirely correct to say that it is converted.