# Writing out to a file in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()

{

string fname,lname;
double pincrease //pay increase percentage,pay;
ifstream infile;
ofstream outfile;

infile.open("C:\\Users\\Connor\\Desktop");
outfile.open("C:\\Users\\Connor\\Desktop");

while(!infile.eof())
{
    infile>>lname>>fname>>pay>>pincrease;
    pay = pay*(pay*pincrease);
    outfile<<fname<<" "<<lname<<" "<<pay<<"\n";
    cin.clear();
}

infile.close();
outfile.close();

}
```

And here are the contents of my `infile`:

```
Miller Andrew 65789.87 5
Green Sheila 75892.56 6
Sethi Amit 74900.50 6.1
```

The information is in the form of `Last Name:First Name:Pay:Pay Increase Percentage`.

The order swap of the first and last name and the exclusion of the pay percent increase when I write to the `outfile` is intentional.

I'm trying to read the contents of the `infile`, modify them, and then write it to an `outfile`.

However when I execute the code I start what I'm pretty sure is an infinite loop but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Are you reading from and writing to your desktop folder?

Comment: [`while(!infile.eof())` is rarely the right thing to do.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/78845)

Comment: @mgamba Yeah. I have two separate text files named infile and outfile on my desktop for convenience.

Comment: It looks like `infile` and `outfile` are pointing to the `Desktop` folder itself.  Also the `lname` declaration is commented out.

Comment: @mgamba Yeah the commenting out was an accident. Put the comments in the post for clarification but I couldn't do it right so I just removed them.

Comment: You still need to specify the actual files you are using.  Also, `double pincrease //pay increase percentage,pay;` should be `double pincrease, pay;`.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these statements likely open files:

```
infile.open("C:\\Users\\Connor\\Desktop");
outfile.open("C:\\Users\\Connor\\Desktop");
```

Rather, they *attempt* (and likely fail) to open your Desktop folder.  Rather, you likely wanted something more like:

```
infile.open("C:\\Users\\Connor\\Desktop\\infile");
outfile.open("C:\\Users\\Connor\\Desktop\\outfile");
```

Of course, `infile` and `outfile` at the end there should be replaced with actual filenames.

You can test whether your file opens succeeded by checking `infile.is_open()` and `outfile.is_open()`.  You might add explicit `if` statements to test this:

```
if (!infile.is_open())
    // report/handle that you couldn't open input file

if (!outfile.is_open())
    // report/handle that you couldn't open output file
```

For your main loop, you shouldn't be testing `eof` as you do.  Rather, use something like this:

```
while(infile>>lname>>fname>>pay>>pincrease)
{
    pay = pay*(pay*pincrease);
    outfile<<fname<<" "<<lname<<" "<<pay<<"\n";
    cin.clear();
}
```

Testing for EOF the way you were will try to read one extra record beyond end of file.

The EOF flag only gets set after a failed read attempt.  Therefore you should always test for EOF after trying to read.

The standard `ifstream` is set up in such a way that a typical `ifstream` input operation (ie. `infile >> item`) will return a reference to an `ifstream` object.  That's how you can do things like `infile >> item1 >> item2 >> item3`.

When you place that in the context of a loop control (as above), `ifstream` has the appropriate operator overloads that cause it to tell `while` whether to keep looping or not based on whether the reads succeeded.

Others have explained that overload magic well enough elsewhere.  More info on the loop termination magic here: [Why istream object can be used as a bool expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117566/why-istream-object-can-be-used-as-a-bool-expression)

Comment: Thank you so much. Especially for the link.

Comment: ihmo rathe unpractical syntax, when you have to decide which data types to read depending on previously read data.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz : Sure, and that's definitely a language design issue.  The standard `ifstream` doesn't lend itself well to a more general language tokenizer / grammar.  But if that's what you need, then you should build something different than the basic tools `ifstream` provides.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
infile.open("C:\\Users\\Connor\\Desktop");
outfile.open("C:\\Users\\Connor\\Desktop");
```

with this

```
infile.open("C:\\Users\\Connor\\infile.txt");
outfile.open("C:\\Users\\Connor\\outfile.txt");
```

The code you have posted will not compile for two reasons. One, The variable `pay` has not been declared and two, you have commented out the termination of the following code.

```
double pincrease //pay increase percentage,pay;
```

Try the below code. Hope it helps

```
            int main()

            {

                string fname,lname;
                double pincrease; //pay increase percentage,pay;
                double pay;
                ifstream infile;
                ofstream outfile;

                infile.open("C:\\Users\\Connor\\infile.txt");
                outfile.open("C:\\Users\\Connor\\outfile.txt");

                while(!infile.eof())
                {
                    infile>>lname>>fname>>pay>>pincrease;
                    pay = pay*(pay*pincrease);
                    outfile<<std::setprecision(2)<<std::showpoint << std::fixed;;
                    outfile<<fname<<" "<<lname<<" "<<pay<<"\n";
                    cin.clear();
                }

                infile.close();
                outfile.close();

            }
```