# Difference between while(!file.eof()) and while(file >> variable)

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

First things first - I've got a text file in which there are binary numbers, one number for each row. I'm trying to read them and sum them up in a C++ program. I've written a function which transforms them to decimal and adds them after that and I know for sure that function's ok. And here's my problem - for these two different ways of reading a text file, I get different results (and only one of these results is right) [my function is decimal()]:

```
ifstream file;
file.open("sample.txt");
int sum = 0;
string BinaryNumber;
while (!file.eof()){
    file >> BinaryNumber;
    sum+=decimal(BinaryNumber);
}
```

and that way my sum is too large, but by a small quantity.

```
ifstream file;
file.open("sample.txt");
int sum = 0;
string BinaryNumber;
while (file >> BinaryNumber){
    sum+=decimal(BinaryNumber);
}
```

and this way gives me the the right sum. After some testing I came to a conclusion that the while loop with eof() is making one more iteration than the other while loop. So my question is - what is the difference between those two ways of reading from a text file? Why the first while loop gives me the wrong result and what may be this extra iteration that it's doing?

Comment: `file >> variable` checks the `file`'s state after input. Whenever you have wrong input, or you hit the EOF, the condition is `false`.

Comment: Your first example fails because `eof()` returns that status of the previous read operation and does not return false until _after_ you have read the end of the stream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that `>>` reads the data first, and then tells you whether it has been a success or not, while `file.eof()` does the check prior to the reading. That is why you get an extra read with the `file.eof()` approach, and that read is invalid.

You can modify the `file.eof()` code to make it work by moving the check to a place after the read, like this:

```
// This code has a problem, too!
while (true) {            // We do not know if it's EOF until we try to read
    file >> BinaryNumber; // Try reading first
    if (file.eof()) {     // Now it's OK to check for EOF
        break;            // We're at the end of file - exit the loop
    }
    sum+=decimal(BinaryNumber);
}
```

However, this code would break if there is no delimiter following the last data entry. So your second approach (i.e. checking the result of `>>`) is the correct one.

**EDIT:** This post was edited in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175114/difference-between-whilefile-eof-and-whilefile-variable/23175142?noredirect=1#comment35443062_23175142).

Comment: Do they both check `eof`, or does the `>>` version check `bad`?

Comment: @Mehrdad The `>>` action depends on whether or not you have C++11: before C++11, it called `operator void*`; starting with C++11, it calls `operator bool()` ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8117635/335858)).

Comment: Actually, checking for `eof()` _after_ reading the input is **also wrong**! This time the error is in the opposite direction: if the last value isn't followed by a space it isn't processed. The only correct approach is to check the status of `file`, i.e., either the conversion to a boolean value or `fail()`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Ah okay, though that wasn't my point. It seems like the boolean conversion uses `fail` instead of `eof` so it's not quite the same semantics in the first place.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thanks for a great comment! I did not realize that the "fix" is broken (I use the conversion to `bool`/ `void*` in my code, but I didn't realize that the eof check in the middle was broken). I edited the answer to explain this.

Answer (score 2):

When using `file.eof()` to test the input, the last input probably fails and the value stays unchanged and is, thus, processed twice: when reading a string, the stream first skips leading whitespace and then reads characters until it finds a space. Assuming the last value is followed by a newline, the stream hasn't touched EOF, yet, i.e., `file.eof()` isn't `true` but reading a string fails because there are no non-whitespace characters.

When using `file >> value` the operation is executed and checked for success: *always* use this approach! The use of `eof()` is only to determine whether the failure to read was due to EOF being hit or something else.