# Is this operator aliasing?

Tags: c++

I don't understand what does mean `typedef void (Testable::*bool_type)() const;`
applied to `operator`

Is such code

```
class Testable {
    typedef void (Testable::*bool_type)() const;

public:

    operator bool_type() const {
     ...
    }
};
```

equivalent to

```
class Testable {

public:

    void operator ()() const {
     ...
    }
};
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Testable {
    typedef void (Testable::*bool_type)() const;

public:

    operator bool_type() const {
     ...
    }
};
```

… defines an implicit conversion to `bool_type`, which is an innaccessible pointer to member type.

This is a C++03 technique to provide implicit conversion to `bool` while avoiding unintended implicit conversions, in particular for function call overload resolution. The returned member pointer converts to `bool` but not to any type that could conceivably be used for a function argument. In contrast, a pure `bool` result would convert to e.g. `int`, and a `void*` result, as [used by C++03 iostreams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8117635/464581), would match a `void*` formal argument.

With C++11 and later you would instead use **`explicit`**, like this:

```
explicit operator bool() const { return whatever; }
```

But better, define a named conversion function, e.g.

```
auto is_empty() const -> bool { return whatever; }
```

That was generally better also in C++03. :-)

---

Regarding “is such code equivalent to…”, no, it's not.

Comment: I know , what is this technique! I asked another question!

Comment: @IvanKush: I elaborated on the answer. Is it more clear now, or did you mean that you asked something about this in another SO question?