# what does if(! (is >> s)) mean?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

Here is an overloaded `>>`operator function:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::vector<int>& v){
  string s;
  if (! (is >> s) )
    return is;
   ...
  return is;
}
```

To my understanding, `if(! (is >> s))` make no sense because the terminal or console will wait until the input from keyboards or other sources enter `s`. So value of condition in `if()` will ultimately be `false`. Who can help?

Comment: It has to be read as "if `is` can't read a string".

Comment: That code is too dense. It should be written in two parts: `is >> s; if (!is)...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `is >> s` attempts to read the string `s` from stream `is`.

`istream`s `operator>>()` returns a reference to `is`.

`istream`s `operator!()` tests if the stream is in an invalid state.  Specifically, it returns `true` if the stream's badbit or failbit has been set.

So,

```
 if (! (is >> s) )
     return is;
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
 is >> s;
 if (is.fail()) return is;    // is.fail() returns true if failbit or badbit are set
```

which means that the function immediately returns if reading a string from the stream fails.   Note that this is distinct from reaching the end of the stream.

Comment: I thin this post is exhaustive but others are also informative to me, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

`istream` does not have to be a console.  It can be a stringstream.  And besides, the 'waiting for user input' is not seen by the application code.  It is asleep while the input stream is being filled (by the operating system, underlying library, ...)

Anyhow: in case the input stream contains no data at all, this condition will be true.

```
std::string s; // empty!
std::stringstream ss(s);

std::vector<std::string> strings;
ss >> strings; // should be empty!
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand what `if (!(is >> s))` means you need to understand what `if (is >> s)` means.

Since `is` is an `std::istream`, operator `>>` returns an `std::istream`. Hence, `is >> s` is an `std::istream`, which inside an `if` must produce a logical value `true` or `false`. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8117566/335858) explains how it is done in different versions of C++. Essentially, `std::istream` evaluates to a true condition when the operation is successful.

Now that you know the meaning of `is >> s`, you can figure out that adding a negation flips that meaning: `!(is >> s)` would be true only when reading an `s` from `is` is unsuccessful. For strings an unsuccessful read means that the stream is in an invalid state, for example, because the end of stream has been reached.

Answer (score -1):

you are doing many things in one line

```
! (is >> s)
```

you take the inputstream and use it to assign the object s, the evaluate teh result of s in the if condition