# Why do while(std::getline) loops work even though std::getline doesn't return a bool?

Tags: c++, while-loop, getline

I've seen many loops like this to read streams:

```
while(std::getline(iss, temp, ' ')) {
    ...
}
```

But I never understood why it worked. In the [documentation for std::getline](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/), it says that it returns the stream, and I don't understand how that is translated into a bool value. Is it reading the eof flag or something? If so, wouldn't this be more accurate:

```
while(!iss.eof()) {
    std::getline(iss, temp, ' ');
}
```

---

Comment: Handy reading: [Why istream object can be used as a bool expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117566/why-istream-object-can-be-used-as-a-bool-expression)

Comment: EOF is one condition it checks for, but it also makes sure the read succeeded. Your EOF loop would be an infinite loop if a read fails, e.g., the physical drive hardware fails or becomes disconnected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::getline` inherits `std::basic_istream`, that inherits `std::basic_ios`, that implements [std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::operator bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

`while` requires a bool resulting expression, thus

```
while(std::getline(iss, temp, ' ')) {
    ...
}
```

is attempted by the compiler under the hood like as

```
while(static_cast<bool>(std::getline(iss, temp, ' '))) {
    ...
}
```

and conversion is performed successfully as

```
while(std::getline(iss, temp, ' ').operator bool()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`while` statements don't require a `bool` specifically for their condition expression.  They require a type that is ***convertible to bool***.

`std::getline` returns [a type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) derived from [`std::basic_ios`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios), which is [convertible to `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).